# How does one use the Open With External Editor feature of Shotwell?

Tags: software, photo-editing, open-source

- Shotwell 0.20.2 > Edit > Preferences > External Editors

  External photo editor: [GIMP Image Editor]
- Clicked on images so that they have blue borders.
- Photos > Open With External Editor

but the `Open With External Editor` is greyed out. How does one use the Open With External Editor feature?

[Edit photos with an external program](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/edit-external.html)

Answer (score 3):

Though the title says [Edit photos with an external program](http://Edit%20photos%20with%20an%20external%20program) the description says:

```
select a photo
```

One at a time works but not multiple.

Comment: I was just about to comment that.